# How Can I change specified dataframe column "Workbooks" with Json value in below data frame to string?

Tags: python, pandas

```
       Workbooks

[{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords'}]

[{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS'}]

[{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx'}]
```

I want to change all values from `"Workbooks"` dataframe column ----->

E.g -> from  `[{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords'}`  to     `Dashboard_5MRecords`

also how will it change if there is extra field , e.g:

```
[{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords','id': '5478994'}]
```

to separate them and make different columns with name and ID?

Comment: Can you clarify, as this question is confusing

Comment: So, a column in dataframe has values in form of --> [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords'} , I want to change all values like this to  Dashboard_5MRecords

Comment: I think similar problems you can find in many questions before. If you have list with single dictionary then first you can convert list with dictionary into normal dictionary `df["Workbooks"] = df["Workbooks"].str[0]`. And later you can use `apply()` with `pandas.Series` to create new columns `name` and `id`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['name'])
```

this assumes that the list is always 1 element long and the 'name' key always exists in that dictionary

Comment: by the way: pandas has `.str` which can work also with `list` and `dictionary` like `df['Workbooks'].str[0].str['name']`

Answer (score 0):

I think similar problems you can find in many questions before.

If you want to get single element from list with dictionary then you can use unusual fact that `.str` can work also with `list` and `dictionary`

```
df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].str[0].str['name']
```

---

Of course you can do the same using `.apply()` with own function

```
def convert(item): 
    return item[0]['name']

df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].apply(convert)
```

or shorter with `lambda`

```
df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: item[0]['name'])
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Workbooks": [
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords'}],
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS'}],
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx'}]
    ]
})

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

# - version 1 -
df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].str[0].str['name']

# - version 2 -
#df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: item[0]['name'])

# - version 3 -
#def convert(item):
#    return item[0]['name']
#df['Workbooks'] = df['Workbooks'].apply(convert)

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

                                          Workbooks
0                 [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords'}]
1  [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS'}]
2            [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx'}]

--- after ---

                            Workbooks
0                 Dashboard_5MRecords
1  Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS
2            Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx
```

---

If you have more values and you want to create more columns then you can use `.apply()` with `pandas.Series()`

```
df[['name', 'id']] = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series(item[0]))
```

or if you don't want to write manually names of columns `['name', 'id']` or dictionares may have different keys

```
new_columns = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series(item[0]))
df = df.join(new_columns)
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Workbooks": [
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords', 'id': '5478994'}],
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS', 'id': '5478995'}],
        [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx', 'id': '5478996'}]
    ]
})

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

# - version 1 -
df[['name', 'id']] = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series(item[0]))
del df['Workbooks']  # remove column
    
# - version 2 - 
#new_columns = df['Workbooks'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series(item[0]))
#df = df.join(new_columns)
#del df['Workbooks']  # remove column

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

                                           Workbooks
0  [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords', 'id': '547899...
1  [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS'...
2  [{'name': 'Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx', 'id': '5...

--- after ---

                                 name       id
0                 Dashboard_5MRecords  5478994
1  Dashboard_5MRecords_PerformanceFIS  5478995
2            Dashboard_5MRecords.twbx  5478996
```